# opsgenie-sdk modeule import error

Tags: python

I am trying write a python program to use the Opsgenie API's to pull some reports.
I installed the https://github.com/opsgenie/opsgenie-python-sdk

When i run my program i get the error message 
"from opsgenie.alert.requests import ListAlertsRequest
ImportError: No module named requests"

The module is present in the site packages folder and I also added the path to the folder to PYTHONPATH. 
It happened for multople module I am not sure if the dependencies work on the opsgenie-sdk.
Has anyone had this issue?

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you print `sys.path` and check directories and files in the places that the path shows?

Comment: OUtput of my python -c 'import sys; print(sys.path)'  '',  ['', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg', '/Users/krm/Documents/Python/Opsgenie', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/opsgenie',